# Codeigniter Form Validation greater_than

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('start_price', 'Starting Price', 'required|decimal');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim|required|decimal|greater_than[start_price]');
```

I have this code. Even i input a price greater than my start_price still the output is The Price field must contain a number greater than Starting Price.

Comment: Do you insert decimal number explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get value of the start price first, then validate.

```
$start_price = $_POST[start_price];
$this->form_validation->set_rules('start_price', 'Starting Price', 'required|decimal');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', "trim|required|decimal|greater_than[$start_price]");
```

Comment: i've already got the solution to this problem and also the same as your :) mine is like this  $this->form_validation->set_rules('start_price', 'Starting Price', 'required|decimal');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim|required|decimal|greater_than['. $this->input->post('start_price'). ']');

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me unless there's any silly mistake. Try using less_than in Starting Price. Silly, I know, but you could give it a try.